# Hold end animation width if clicked after a hover animation with CSS

Tags: css, list, animation, hover, click

I have a list of items with an indicator that expands on hover using simple CSS animations, see the jsfiddle below.

https://jsfiddle.net/jsiman/p9kqoc8h/8/

```
@keyframes indicator-hover-on {
  0% {
    width: 10px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 20px;
  }
}

@keyframes indicator-hover-off {
  0% {
    width: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 10px;
  }
}
```

When a section is clicked, I want that indicator to remain expanded. Any hovers on other sections will still trigger the animation but I want to be able to show an "active" indicator state. When another section is clicked, it will show the "active" indicator state and the old one will transition back to the unexpanded state.

Is this possible with pure CSS transitions? I know how to achieve this functionality using d3.js and I want to stay away from jQuery.

Comment: you can't do it with css alone, you'll need some (relatively simple) javascript - jQuery won't be necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do not think that's possible.
from your question it sounds like you want it to happen during a click.
click event is something that is captured by javascript, or any other way that implements javascript, i do not know any other way to catch events.

Comment: I ended up going with Angular animations and click/hover listeners, may do a Medium post on it later. I figured Angular checking for animations would be more efficient than any looping code I would write. Thanks!